# Problem with electric potential involving a delta function

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, charge, potential, dirac-delta-distributions

> Consider $V(r)=\dfrac{Ae^{-\lambda r}}{r}$ with $\lambda, A$ constants with appropriate units. Calculate the electric field, the charge density $\rho$ and the total charge $Q_{tot}$. (HINT: In a certain step you can consider a Dirac function)

I have already calculated the electric field and the charge density, but I don't end up understanding how am I supposed to use the Dirac function, for the total charge? At the end, I also want to ask about in which situations it seems to be appropriate to use the Dirac function, for the moment I understand it for moments in which an integral indeterminates in a particular point, and the evaluation in the integral is a certain constant except in that point. Any explanation about both of my complications?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gauss's law, differential form, for potentials reads:
$$\frac{\rho_Q}{\epsilon_0} = -\nabla^2 V(r).$$

We can prove that:
$$\begin{align}
-\nabla^2 \frac{1}{r} &= 4\pi \delta(\vec{r}) \\
& = \frac{\delta(r)}{r^2},\end{align}$$
which is a fancy way of saying that a point charge produces a potential proportional to $1/r$. Note that 
$$ \frac{A \mathrm{e}^{-\lambda r}}{r} \approx \frac{A(1 - \lambda r + \ldots)}{r}, $$
for $r \lambda \ll 1$. The first term of that is the potential of a point charge, so the Laplacian of the potential will produce a delta function.

Comment: Can you explain me a little bit more about what you mean for "a fancy way of saying that a point charge produces a potential proportional to $1/r$?

Comment: What I mean is that $Q\delta(\vec{r} - \vec{x})$ is, effectively, the charge density that describes a point charge.